# how to bind an thumbnail image in repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I have an requirement where  in my datatable.
I have  3  columns.

```
serverpath,image name, id
```

Now I need to  get the imagepath  from that  the datatable[serverpath] and  bind it in a  repeater control or  gridview  control and  show the thumbnail images there. Actaully in the path `d:/application/images`  folder I have  images.

When I  bind to repeater control or grid control I need  to  convert the  orignal images into thumbnail  and  display  in  reater control. In   (5x5)  rows x columns but I need to  show only thumbnail images no other  details  like[server path,id].

ex:

```
thumailimge1   thumailimge2 thumailimge3   thumailimge4 thumailimge5   
thumailimge6   thumailimge7 thumailimge8   thumailimge9 thumailimge10
```

so   once the  user  click on this  thumbnail orignal  image  will  be  displayed in a new  window

hope my question is clear...

how can I achieve this functionality?
any help  would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom asp.net handler (or even a plain aspx page where you manually write to the Response) to serve the image as the source for an img tag in your repeater

ASHX:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomImageHandler.aspx

http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler

ASPX:

http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/03/23/4180.aspx

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19463